# Looking to assign subgroup values to of a group to a common value in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a series of phone numbers that have individual names associated with them.  The phone numbers are not necessarily unique, and sometimes the name associated with them is missing. I would like to fill in the names with the following rules:

- If a grouped phone number has blank entries and only a single name available, I would like to replace the blank names with the one available.
- If the grouped number has entries with multiple non-blank names, then I cannot determine who belongs to that phone number and so I make no changes.

Here is the original table:

```
library("dplyr")
phone = c("1234","1234","1234","4567","4567","4567","4567","4567");phone
sgroup = c("","Jones","","Smith","","Smith","Williams","Jones");sgroup

DATA = data.frame(phone,sgroup);DATA
```

And here is how I want it to look:

```
phone1 = c("1234","1234","1234","4567","4567","4567","4567","4567");phone1
sgroup1 = c("Jones","Jones","Jones","Smith","","Smith","Williams","Jones");sgroup1

DATA1 = data.frame(phone1,sgroup1)
```

Note the "1234" since it originally had only 'Jones" and Blanks(NAs) assigned, so I assigned all records in that group to 'Jones. The second number (4567) had multiple names assigned, so I was unable to determine a common name so no assignment was made.

I can determine which phones have blank or non-blank name assignments, but I have been unable to determine how to assign them back to the blank records in that group.

```
Countdf1 <- DATA %>% count(phone,sgroup)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original `data.table` solution (see the bottom of the post for a more performant implementation):

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(phone = c("1234","1234","1234","4567","4567","4567","4567","4567"),
                 sgroup = c("","Jones","","Smith","","Smith","Williams","Jones"))
dt[, ngrp := .(.(unique(sgroup[sgroup != ""]))), by = "phone"][lengths(ngrp) == 1, sgroup := unlist(ngrp)][, 1:2]
#>    phone   sgroup
#> 1:  1234    Jones
#> 2:  1234    Jones
#> 3:  1234    Jones
#> 4:  4567    Smith
#> 5:  4567         
#> 6:  4567    Smith
#> 7:  4567 Williams
#> 8:  4567    Jones
```

This works by adding a helper column `ngrp`. For each unique `phone` value, it creates a list containing a vector of unique `sgroup` values. (`.(` is `data.table` shorthand for `list`). That list gets stored in `ngrp`.

```
dt[, ngrp := .(.(unique(sgroup[sgroup != ""]))), by = "phone"]; dt
#>    phone   sgroup                 ngrp
#> 1:  1234                         Jones
#> 2:  1234    Jones                Jones
#> 3:  1234                         Jones
#> 4:  4567    Smith Smith,Williams,Jones
#> 5:  4567          Smith,Williams,Jones
#> 6:  4567    Smith Smith,Williams,Jones
#> 7:  4567 Williams Smith,Williams,Jones
#> 8:  4567    Jones Smith,Williams,Jones
```

For the subset of `dt` where the length of the vector in `ngrp` is `1`, set `sgroup` to the corresponding value stored in `ngrp` (use `unlist` to avoid the warning message about list to character type conversion).

```
dt[lengths(ngrp) == 1, sgroup := unlist(ngrp)]; dt
#>    phone   sgroup                 ngrp
#> 1:  1234    Jones                Jones
#> 2:  1234    Jones                Jones
#> 3:  1234    Jones                Jones
#> 4:  4567    Smith Smith,Williams,Jones
#> 5:  4567          Smith,Williams,Jones
#> 6:  4567    Smith Smith,Williams,Jones
#> 7:  4567 Williams Smith,Williams,Jones
#> 8:  4567    Jones Smith,Williams,Jones
```

Subset on the first two columns.

```
dt[, 1:2]
#>    phone   sgroup
#> 1:  1234    Jones
#> 2:  1234    Jones
#> 3:  1234    Jones
#> 4:  4567    Smith
#> 5:  4567         
#> 6:  4567    Smith
#> 7:  4567 Williams
#> 8:  4567    Jones
```

Alternatively, drop the helper column.

```
dt[, ngrp := NULL]; dt
#>    phone   sgroup
#> 1:  1234    Jones
#> 2:  1234    Jones
#> 3:  1234    Jones
#> 4:  4567    Smith
#> 5:  4567         
#> 6:  4567    Smith
#> 7:  4567 Williams
#> 8:  4567    Jones
```

A faster solution would be to do the clean-up in a function that can be called by `phone` group. This runs about twice as fast by avoiding the helper column.

```
fCleanGroup <- function(x) {
  xu <- unique(x[nchar(x) != 0L])
  if (length(xu) == 1L) xu else x
}

dt[, sgroup := fCleanGroup(sgroup), by = "phone"]

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(fun = copy(dt)[, sgroup := fCleanGroup(sgroup), by = "phone"],
                               lst = copy(dt)[, ngrp := .(.(unique(sgroup[sgroup != ""]))), by = "phone"][lengths(ngrp) == 1, sgroup := unlist(ngrp)][, 1:2],
                               copy(dt))
#> Unit: microseconds
#>      expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
#>       fun  485.8  595.75  653.372  616.05  680.00 1164.2   100
#>       lst 1058.4 1256.75 1383.188 1302.90 1425.35 3685.1   100
#>  copy(dt)   11.9   21.10   27.425   27.65   31.00   62.6   100
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I will need to investigate data.table further, it appears to be very powerful.

Comment: Sure. Since you're interested, when I get a minute, I'll break down the logic in the answer.

Comment: Thank you again for the details and the response.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you need.

We go through all unique phone numbers (a kind of "group by") and then check if there's more than 2 unique names associated or if there are no missing names at all. If there are only two unique names and one of them is missing, that's when we apply your rule number 1. Else, we don't do anything.

```
phone = c("1234","1234","1234","4567","4567","4567","4567","4567")
sgroup = c("","Jones","","Smith","","Smith","Williams","Jones")

DATA = data.frame(phone,sgroup);


for (phone in unique(DATA$phone)) {
    names <- unique(DATA$sgroup[DATA$phone == phone])
    if (length(names) > 2 || all(!names %in% c(NA, "", NULL))) {
        next
    } else {
        df <- DATA[DATA$phone == phone, ]
        df$sgroup <- names[!names %in% c(NA, "", NULL)]
        DATA[DATA$phone == phone, ] <- df
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I worked through this and understand the logic.  Thank you for the solution.

Comment: Can you accept my solution as the answer, then?